# How to find a hidden file?

Tags: command-line, find, hidden-files

Somewhere on my 10T NAS devise is a file named exactly `.avi`.

I have tried `find`, `locate` and `ls`. All return either all files ending with extension `.avi` or nothing at all.

How can I find it explicitly?

Comment: Try `ls -al` this will show list of hidden folders and files in current directory.

Comment: @snoop, No, >ls -al; will show a list of all files and directories including hidden.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put what you need to find inside double quotes

```bsh
sudo find / -name ".avi" -print
```

(`sudo` if you want to search the whole disk).